# WPF How to build docked resizable expanders and grid using XAML only?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to build a wpf application that has two expanders one on the left and other on the right and grid in between them both. The expanders must be able to resize themselves correspondingly automatically resizing the grid in between them as shown below.
[image]

With some XAML pasted below I was able to resize the left side expander but the right side expander and the grid are not shown.

```
    <Grid>
    <!--<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>-->
    <DockPanel>
    <Expander DockPanel.Dock="Left" x:Name="ProjectsExpander" Header="Projects" IsExpanded="True" ExpandDirection="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">            
        <Grid Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Expander}},Path=ActualWidth}">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Column="0">
        <something here/>
            </Grid>
            <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="2" Background="{DynamicResource BorderBrush}" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndCurrent" ResizeDirection="Columns"/>
        </Grid>
    </Expander>

    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Left" Background="Green" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <TextBlock Text="Test"/>
    </Grid>

    <Expander DockPanel.Dock="Right" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Header="Properties" ExpandDirection="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="235">
        <Grid Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Expander}},Path=ActualWidth}">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <GridSplitter Grid.Column="0" Width="2" Background="{DynamicResource BorderBrush}" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndCurrent" ResizeDirection="Columns"/>
            <Border Grid.Column="1" Width="130"/>
        </Grid>
    </Expander>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

As you can see I have used a DockPanel to dock the controls but I had tried to dock them using a Grid with ColumnDefinitions and I get the same result. So can anyone please tell me how can I get the application to have two expanders on each sides and a grid in between and be able to resize the expanders and thus also automatically resize the grid as well?

Comment: Old question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35455094/net-gridsplitter-to-resize-one-column.
But the answer was never received.

Comment: Your Width binding looks crazy. :)
Please clarify.
Do you need to resize the Expander itself or just its contents?

Comment: I want to resize it's contents.

Comment: And why does my width binding look crazy? The width was not stretching to fit its parent expander by default so I had to make such a binding.

Comment: 1) You set a binding to the Read Only property, while trying to act on it by changing the source.

2) You set an anchor to the Parent element, which is always larger than its content. The content takes the size of the Parent. The parent is enlarged because of this. Which again leads to a change in the content.
The result is a looping to infinity.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Grid` and put the `GridSplitters` in separate columns:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Expander x:Name="ProjectsExpander" Header="Projects" IsExpanded="True" ExpandDirection="Right">
        <TextBlock>...</TextBlock>
    </Expander>

    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />

    <Grid Grid.Column="2" Background="Yellow">
        <TextBlock>...</TextBlock>
    </Grid>

    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />

    <Expander Grid.Column="4" Header="Properties" ExpandDirection="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="235">
        <TextBlock>...</TextBlock>
    </Expander>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Using your code when I drag the grid splitters the columns are resizing but the expanders contained within the columns are not resizing. I want the expanders to resize along with their columns.

Comment: The left-most does, doesn't it. Try to replace the `TextBlock` in my example with something wider.

Comment: No it doesn't. The content of the expanders are not resizing. I actually want the content (and not the header) of the expanders to resize. That's why inorder to resize the content of the expanders I had put the GridSplitters inside the expanders in my code in the question.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Are you saying that the expander does not expand? It does for me and the column (`Expander`) then resizes. Did you try *my*  example?

Comment: Yes I tried your sample. It resizes the columns but doesn't resize the content of the expander. See my previous comment. I've updated it.

Comment: Resize the content according to what? The content is *expanded*. It's not resized. The column is.

Comment: The expander content must resize according to the expander's column. Or to make thing more clear: For example, If the width of the column is resized to say 200 then the expander's content's width should be resized to 200 minus expander's header's width.
You see what I'm saying?

Comment: Minus the header width is up to you to implement. The `Expander` stretches to fit the column.

Comment: The expnder is stretching but expander's content is not stretching  to fit the column.

Comment: It depends on the contents.

Comment: I have tried using grid as the content. Should I use something else?

Comment: Did you also try to remove the `Width` so it actually stretches?

Comment: Ya if I remove the width property of the grid and set it's background to green, the grid appers as thin vertical green line and doesn't resize. See the screenshot here: https://imgur.com/LbaI9Yz

Comment: Copy and paste my markup into a new window and replace the first `TextBlock` in the first `Expander` with a `Grid`: `<Grid Background="Green"> <TextBlock>...</TextBlock></Grid>`. And then post a new screenshot.

Comment: Looks like I figured out where the problem is occurring. All this time I was using a UI library called HandyControls to style my application. I copied your code into a new application that uses the default wpf UI and the one that uses the HandyControls UI. The expander content resizes as expected in the application using the default wpf UI but doesn't resize in the one using the HandyControls UI. So it looks like there is some problem in the styling of the expander in HandyControls. I'll post this issue in HandyControl's GitHub repo. Thanks for your time and effort @mm8.

Comment: @jNerd: Cool. Please remember to accept the answer if your original issue has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to resize Expander content:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Expander Header="Projects" IsExpanded="True" ExpandDirection="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                <Button Content="Left" Padding="15 5"/>
            </Grid>
            <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="2" Background="Red" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndCurrent"/>
        </Grid>
    </Expander>

    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Left" Background="Green" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
              Grid.Column="1">
        <TextBlock Text="Test"/>
    </Grid>

    <Expander VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Header="Properties" ExpandDirection="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                  Grid.Column="2">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <GridSplitter Grid.Column="0" Width="2" Background="Red" ResizeBehavior="CurrentAndNext"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
            <Border Grid.Column="1" Background="Aqua" MinWidth="50"/>
        </Grid>
    </Expander>
</Grid>
```